# What does Allen's line about the floatation device mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-other-guys

In "The other guys", Allen says:

> Anything you say or do can be used as a floatation device.

What's funny about it?

Comment: Depends on the execution of dialogue but still bit unclear to me or might be because i didn’t watched the film.

Answer (score 10):

Allen Gamble (Ferrell) forgets how the Miranda Rights speech goes, so his partner (Wahlberg) jokingly makes him finish the sentence with a bit from another familiar speech: the saftey speech in airplanes that at one point tells you that [certain things around you could be used as a floatation device](http://www.boeing.com/boeing/commercial/safety/faq.page#FAQ16). Thus, he's making Allen sound like a flight attendant rather than a cop.